# ¿Como comparar dos columnas de un mismo data frame, y crear una nueva columna, si es == colocar el valor de columna, sino el valor de otra?

Tags: python, jupyter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El DF_prueba tiene estas 3 columnas, quiero adicionarle una tercera, que cumpla lo siguiente, si REGLA2!=REGLA1, colocar valor de REGLA2, sino valor de REGLA 1, luego solo esa nueva columna, adicionarla a otro DF_x

Comment: En este caso, se que tienen los mismos valores, pero me he equivocado en el orden de los valores de las celdas de la REGLA 2 deberían ser a la inversa de la REGLA 1, lo siento

Comment: Hola María, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! puedes editar tu pregunta y corregir cualquier error que se te haya deslizado.

Comment: porfavor adjunta la tabla como texto y no como foto para que sea más fácil reproducir el problema

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que crear una función que haga la comparación:

```
import pandas as pd

def crear_columna_nueva(row):
    if row['REGLA 1'] == row['REGLA 2']:
        return row['REGLA 1']
    return row['REGLA 2']

DF_prueba = pd.DataFrame() # aquí está tu dataframe con los datos que sean
DF_x = pd.DataFrame() # dataframe con los datos de DF_x que tiene el mismo número de filas que DF_prueba

# puedes guardar el resultado en DF_prueba también si quieres
DF_x['REGLA 3'] = DF_prueba.apply(crear_columna_nueva, axis=1)
```

IMPORTANTE: los dos DataFrames DF_x y DF_prueba tienen siempre el mismo número de filas!

En este caso he creado un ejemplo muy simple que guarda el resultado en la columa REGLA 3.